# sudo docker run: unbound variable error

Tags: docker

I installed docker.io on my Linux laptop and did a `docker pull` on a container that is publicly available on the docker website.

I am trying to run it interactively with the following command, but I get an error:

```
sudo docker pull nucleotides/sga
sudo docker run -i nucleotides/sga /bin/bash

+ set -o nounset
/usr/local/bin/run: line 9: $2: unbound variable
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That image is provided by a user, not Docker themselves.

It uses an entrypoint script, which is interpreting your `/bin/bash` command as the first argument. You can take a look at the script here: https://github.com/nucleotides/docker-sga/blob/master/run. It has the following information regarding arguments:

```
# The first argument is the location of the reads in the container filesystem.
# The will be present in a read-only directory
READS=$2

# The second argument is a directory with write-access where the final
# assembly should be written to.
DIR=$3
```

It would be fair to say that this script isn't following best practices, it is very confusing gobbling input in this way. See the docs for more on best practices: https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint.